# camel springboot and hawtio integration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, hawtio

I am working on integrating the camel springboot component with hawtio. I can't see the camel tab in the hawtio UI. I am using below dependencies of springboot camel and hawtio

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This the sample route i configured, route is working as expected

```
@Component
public class SampleRoute extends org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder{

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("kafka:test123?brokers=localhost:9092&allowManualCommit=true&autoCommitEnable=false&breakOnFirstError=true&maxPollRecords=1&synchronous=true")
    .process(exchange -> {
        exchange.getIn().setBody("test1234");
    }).to("stream:out");
}



}
```

After reading many articles , i added below set of properties and it seems to have any effect.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hawtio,jolokia
management.endpoints.jolokia.sensitive=false
endpoints.jolokia.sensitive = false
hawtio.authenticationEnabled=false
spring.jmx.enabled=true
camel.springboot.endpoint-runtime-statistics-enabled=true
management.endpoint.camelroutes.enabled=true
management.info.camel.enabled=true
management.endpoint.camelroutes.enabled=true
management.endpoint.camelroutes.read-only=true
camel.springboot.jmx-enabled=true
```

One of the solution worked for me is by downgrading to camel 2.X , but no luck with camel 3.X

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Camel Context Not Listed in Hawtio JMX At All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757389/camel-context-not-listed-in-hawtio-jmx-at-all)

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working. I added that dependency and no change is reflected.

Comment: i can see CameRouteController mbean , but there is no chart or camel tab.

Comment: @Bedla I got it working, the link you pointed was helpful. I had two versions of camel and resolved the dependency . Thanks

Comment: @GirishBhatM Great you got it working. You can write your answer yourself for anyone else who face the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, following the link as suggested. I had to remove the conflicting dependencies and adding below dependency worked.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```