# Unable to see Camel section in Hawtio in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-boot-actuator, hawtio

I've Apache Camel 3.4.2 and hawtio-springboot 2.10.2 with the following in the application.properties of a Spring Boot (2.3.3) application:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hawtio,jolokia,health
hawtio.authenticationEnabled=false
management.endpoint.hawtio.enabled=true
management.endpoint.jolokia.enabled=true
```

But I'm not seeing Camel section in Hawtio. I was able to see it before I upgraded Camel/Spring/Hawtio versions. Is this not working with this version of Camel? Do I need to configure anything else? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since Camel 3 you need camel-management dependency [Camel Context Not Listed in Hawtio JMX At All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757389/camel-context-not-listed-in-hawtio-jmx-at-all)

Comment: Thanks - it's now working! :)